# How to stop "dating" advertising on Gmail?

Tags: gmail, ads

I really like the new ads in Gmail, because I've been able to find very cheap host providers for my websites, however **I find it boring it continuously suggest "dating", "meetgirl"** etc. I'm really not interested in that spam and I meticulously erase those kind of ads with the following reasons:

- not interested
- not appropriate
- too personal

But regardless of what I do, those kind of ads still shows up. I'm really not interested in that messages, and no, they are not "customized" for me, because I do not visit *that* kind of websites. Seems that somehow it still thinks I would like that kind of advertising while in reality not. Should I start using an ad blocker? or is there any way to stop that spam now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest [installing uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation) extension. There are several reasons to use adblockers, such as security and faster page load times.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.google.com/settings/ads/authenticated to personalise the adverts you receive.

Add topics you like so you might receive more ads of those kind.